# Styling autopopulated text fields

Tags: css, html, safari

I'm trying to style my text fields, and all seems to be working - except that when Safari autopopulates texts fields, they come up in the really ugly mustard yellow that I want to change - looks ridiculous on the log in form.  What property do I style to change that color?

The text fields are like so on Safari's inspector:

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

This is used for safari and chrome basically,

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #u {
        color:green; /* Safari only */
    }
}`

Comment: I don't quite understand how one would use this is a css.scss file?  Perhaps if you put it alongside some regular css to show how it works?